# List all Server Features/Roles in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I have the following code to output all features and roles installed:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
$Arr = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed -match “True”} | Select-Object -Property Name
$loopCount = $Arr.Count
For($i=0; $i -le $loopCount; $i++) {
    Write-Host $Arr[$i]
}
```

However, the output is:

```
@{Name=Backup-Features}
@{Name=Backup}
@{Name=Backup-Tools}
```

How can I get rid of the `@` and `{}`'s ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Select -ExpandProperty Name` instead of `Select -Property Name`

Alternatively and also, I recommend using Foreach-Object instead of a C-style for loop.

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Get-WindowsFeature | 
    Where-Object {$_.Installed -match “True”} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    Write-Host
```

Or

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Get-WindowsFeature | 
    Where-Object {$_.Installed -match “True”} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Name | Write-Host
    }
```

Comment: This is great - what is the difference to cause such output?

Comment: ExpandProperty: Can only be used with one property, it gives the property value to the pipeline; Property: Can have multiple selections and calculated properties, sends a new custom object down the pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

How about a nice one liner?

```
Get-WindowsFeature | ? {$_.Installed -match “True”} | Select -exp Name
```

Comment: Always great to have a one liner. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a totally static solution, this should work:

```
Write-Host $Arr[$i].Substring(2, $Arr[$i].Length-3)
```

If you're looking for a solution that looks specifically for those symbols and removes them, it would be a little different. Based on your question though, this should be just fine.

Comment: Can you use Substring against an array as this does not appear to work.

Comment: @PnP No. Substring can only be used against individual strings. In my example, I am simply modifying how the string is displayed, not modifying the actual string in the array.